Spire.PDF Replace Text and keep the Original Colour
I would like to create a Python tool that can edit PDF documents. The challenge I'm facing is that I'm unable to maintain the original text color.
I've discovered Spire.PDF, which offers a wide range of features and works exceptionally well. With this library, I can preserve the text size and font, but I'm unable to retain the color or the formatting (e.g., bold, italic) of the text.
Here's the code I've developed so far:
from spire.pdf import *
from spire.pdf.common import *

# Create an object of PdfDocument
pdf = PdfDocument()

# Load a PDF document
pdf.LoadFromFile("Spire.pdf")

# Get user input for the text to replace
input_text = input("Enter the text to replace: ")
output_text = input("Enter the replacement text: ")

# Loop through the pages in the document
for i in range(pdf.Pages.Count):
    # Get a page
    page = pdf.Pages.get_Item(0)
    # Create an object of PdfTextReplacer class based on the page
    replacer = PdfTextReplacer(page)
    # Find and replace all matched text with a new color
    replacer.ReplaceAllText(input_text, output_text, Color.get_Black())

# Save the document
pdf.SaveToFile("output/ReplaceAllMatches.pdf")
pdf.Close()

print(f"Text '{input_text}' has been replaced with '{output_text}' in the output PDF.")

The goal is to enhance this code to not only maintain the original text color but also preserve the formatting, such as whether the text is in bold, italic, or a specific font style (e.g., Arial Regular, Arial Bold). This would ensure that the edited PDF document retains the same visual appearance as the original, making it seamless for the end-user.
To achieve this, I may need to explore alternative PDF manipulation libraries or delve deeper into the Spire.PDF documentation to uncover additional functionality. Maintaining the original formatting and color of the text is crucial for preserving the integrity and aesthetics of the PDF document.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to enhance the existing code to meet these requirements. Your expertise in this area would be invaluable in helping me develop a robust and user-friendly PDF editing tool.

Thank you for the insights. I'd appreciate guidance on:


PDF Libraries: What capabilities in PyPDF2, PDFPlumber, or others could help maintain formatting?


Extracting Formatting/Color: How can I identify/extract the original formatting/color details?


Applying Formatting/Color: If extracted, how do I apply when replacing text?


Library Limitations: What are the key limitations of PyPDF2, PyMuPDF for preserving formatting/color?


Any advice would be greatly helpful as I seek an effective solution to maintain the PDF's original appearance.

You are replacing the instances of the text with a black color. If you want to retain the original color, you should remove Color.get_Black() from this code:
replacer.ReplaceAllText(input_text, output_text, Color.get_Black())


Thank you very much, do you know how to transfer e.g. a prefix like that the text is bold?
